# Where to start to learn about free boundary problems?

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I am interested in analysis of PDEs in free boundary problems. Please recommend some sources for me to learn about this.

I would prefer Sobolev space setting as opposed to Holder spaces.

Comment: As suggested in the answer with my (+1) , always let the problem be leading for a setting; do not let the setting be leading for a problem.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend (without any reservations)

[A Geometric Approach to Free Boundary Problems](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Geometric-Approach-Boundary-Problems-Mathematics/dp/0821837842/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1389461684&sr=8-3&keywords=free%20boundary%20problems), by Luis Caffarelli & Sandro Salsa,

as both the authors are currently among the leaders in the area.

I would also recommend a good and pleasant reading by Avner Friedman:

http://www.ams.org/notices/200008/fea-friedman.pdf

It is to be noted that A. Friedman's book on the same topic (now in Dover edition) is where I learned (I am not an expert though). Nevertheless, it is not a reader friendly text.